# How exactly angular2 quickstart works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I'm reading the [angular2 quickstart project](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) and I understand that I need to run `npm install` to install the dependencies and then `npm start` to run the start script, which is in `package.json` and is:

```
 "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" "
```

First of all, what is 'concurrently'? Also, as I understood, `tsc` is the typescript transpiler, right? So, can I just transpile the `.ts` file by hand? How should I do this?

Also, where in the project are the definitions that import these .js files that were transpiled?

There's too much abstraction and packages here, I want to transpile by hand and understand what's happening.

Comment: Get a book for instance ng2-book read it if you want to understand, if you want to quickly start app, and slowly learn what is going on look to angular-cli

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I'm reading a book but it used the browser's live compilation

Comment: If you really want to practice/understand Typscript, try starting with https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html instead of angular2 starter app.

Comment: Here is package you ask https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the command bit by bit

- "start" - this runs when you run npm start
- "tsc" - run the typescript compiler
- "&&" - also run the next command
- "concurrently" - this is another npm package that lets you run up to 4 commands concurrently. This is included in the devDependencies section of the package.json. The way this script is set up, it will run "tsc -w" and "lite-server" concurrently.
- "tsc -w" - run the typescript compiler in watch mode
- "lite-server" - run a node server that locally hosts your files allowing you to go to localhost:XXXX and see your project in the browser

Comment: where is tsc and concurrently installed? they're not listed as dependencies

Comment: also, how the tsc command works if I don't have it installed?

Comment: it is installed, however the dependency in package.json is simply "typescript"